# If $F$ is a closed subset of $[a,b]$ and length of $F$, $|F| = 0$ then is $F$ an empty set. True or False?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

According to me it is false because $F$ might be a singleton subset in $[a,b]$. If $F = \{x\}$, then it contains a constant sequence which converges to itself and hence it is closed. Length of $F, |F| = 0 $but $F$ is not empty

Comment: What do you mean  by "length"?  The Lebesgue measure?

Comment: That is correct, at least for any notion of length in which that singleton has length zero. In particular for the usual (Lebesgue measure) notion of length.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the question itself in the body, an not just in the title.  Please also format your mathematics using MathJax.

Comment: Well not exactly..in my textbook it is given that If G is an open subset of [a,b] , G = U In, In are open pairwise disjoint subintervals, then length |G| is defined as |G| = |I1| + |I2|...

Comment: @user519535 from that definition and additivity of length it follows that the length of a singleton is zero. In fact $|\{x\}|=|[a,b]|-|[a,x)|-|(x,b]|=b-a-x+a-b+x=0$, where $[a,x)$ and $(x,b]$ are open intervals in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Just to illustrate how false this claim is: the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is a closed subset of $[0,1]$ which has measure zero, and it is not only nonempty, it is uncountably infinite.

Answer (score 1):

$\{a\}$ is a subset of $[a,b]$ which is closed, but $|\{a\}|=0$.